# JS filter an array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter

I have the following JSON:

```
"menu":[
    {
        "name": "Home",
        "icon": "ri-home-4-line",
        "layoutCode": "",
        "active": ["h1"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Cust", 
        "layoutCode": "",
        "icon": "ri-user-2-fill",
        "active": ["c1", "c2"]

    }
]
```

What I would like to do is filter by active and get the parent object.

I tried with this:

```
json_menu.menu.filter(record => record.active === 'c1')
```

but i obtain an empty object.

Comment: _"I have the following JSON:..."_ - No you don't. That's just an object (if we assume that you just missed to also post the wrapping `{ }`) with a `"menu"` property that stores an array of objects... -> [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: _"but i obtain an empty object."_ - Because `"active"` is an array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if `active` includes `"c1"`.

```js
const menu = [
  {
    name: "Home",
    icon: "ri-home-4-line",
    layoutCode: "",
    active: ["h1"]
  },
  {
    name: "Cust",
    layoutCode: "",
    icon: "ri-user-2-fill",
    active: ["c1", "c2"]
  }
];

const result = menu.filter(m => m.active.includes("c1"));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`active`is an array. Try:

```
json_menu.menu.filter(record => record.active.includes('c1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `includes` instead of `===`

```
json_menu.menu.filter(record => record.active.includes('c1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

json_menu.menu.filter(record => record.active.includes('c1'))

use includes function to check item in array